# Sharepoint 2013 List validation - two fields contain text

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

Pardon this newbie question on SharePoint list validation, I have been researching this for days

1. SharePoint 2013
2. SharePoint LIST validation since you cannot compare two fields in FIELD validation
3. Two fields in same list:

field#1 -- Employee's Email Address

field#2 -- Vendor Contact Name

4. Validation - If both fields contain data then don't allow the form to save. Basically if either field is blank allow the form to save.

Comment: I know this works for one field at a time:
=ISBLANK([Employee's Email Address])=TRUE

Sales

19

=COUNTA([Column1], [Column2])

Counts the number of nonblank columns (2)

Sales

19

=COUNTA([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])

Counts the number of nonblank columns (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below formula :

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Column1]), ISBLANK([Column2])), true, false)
```

Comment: thats great!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you